# How to add data to events in applandeo calenderView?

Tags: java, android, android-library, android-calendar, calendarview

There is a vey nice libray(https://github.com/Applandeo/Material-Calendar-View) for customizing the android calenderview . Like for example, for adding events to the calenderview there is class named Eventday.java, which takes calender object and a drawable object as parameters to initialize. I wish it could have take a string value too so that i can also store a descrption of the event, because there is no point in adding events to the calender if one cannot add details about the event(string datatype). Can some one provide a workaround for my problem?

```
List<EventDay> events = new ArrayList<>();
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

//we cannot details about the event(string data) while initializing the EventDay class
events.add(new EventDay(calendar, R.drawable.absentic));
```

Comment: where you want to show that description?

Comment: I want to show that descrption in a new dialog box when user clicks on the date of the event

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First Make a Custom Class

```
import com.applandeo.materialcalendarview.EventDay;

import java.util.Calendar;

public class MyEventDay extends EventDay implements Parcelable {
    private String mNote;
    public MyEventDay(Calendar day, int imageResource, String note) {
        super(day, imageResource);
        mNote = note;
    }
    public  String getNote() {
        return mNote;
    }
    private MyEventDay(Parcel in) {
        super((Calendar) in.readSerializable(), in.readInt());
        mNote = in.readString();
    }
    public static final Creator<MyEventDay> CREATOR = new Creator<MyEventDay>() {
        @Override
        public MyEventDay createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new MyEventDay(in);
        }
        @Override
        public MyEventDay[] newArray(int size) {
            return new MyEventDay[size];
        }
    };
    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel parcel, int i) {
        parcel.writeSerializable(getCalendar());
        parcel.writeInt(getImageResource());
        parcel.writeString(mNote);
    }
    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

**Adding Event In Calender**

```
 mEventDays.add(new MyEventDay(calender, R.drawable.ic_note_sticky, "I am Event");
```

**For Retriving String**

```
 calendarView.setOnDayClickListener(new OnDayClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDayClick(EventDay eventDay) {
                 Log.e("Event",((MyEventDay) eventDay).getNote()+" <--");
            }
        });
```

Its Work For me , I Hope its Helpfull to you also

Comment: seems to be a nice workaround...but a small issue ..in the function writeToParcel function, the getImageResource() is not recognizable, (on hovering error shown as "
Cannot resolve method")..it think it should be getImageDrawable() from the original EventDay class, but then there will be a cast error due to parcel.writeInt()

Comment: Its works for me , customize as per your requrement

Comment: i converted the drawable to bitmap, and the wrote to parcel and not its working!...Thanks a lot brother, you r a life saver...can you also please explain your code a bit.. like i understood you extended the original class in a custom class to inherit its features but why did you implement Parcelable ? ...anyway thanks again:)

Comment: i am just grab the code from google and its work for me, link is here https://applandeo.com/blog/material-calendar-view-customized-calendar-widget-android/ please check it

Answer (score 0):

I used this method to display small popup note when user clicks on any date.

1. Declared: `Map<Date,String> eventNotes = new HashMap<>()`
2. While updating calendar events for every date, populated the `eventNotes` with required notes and date as key
3. In Calendar `setOnDayClickListener` retrieved `eventNote` using the key `eventDay.getCalendar().getTime()`
4. Then used a dialog popup to show that note